# Different output showing on Xcode's Playground

Tags: xcode, console, xcode6, output, swift-playground

I can get the console output if I "Show Assistant Editor", but I don't want it there the whole time, just want it when I'm checking values. I've seen in videos that people can click the little (+) circle to see the results[image], but when I click it this appears[image] I was wondering how I'd be able to get something that looks like this when I press the (+) ? [image]

Using: Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 0):

I see this since Xcode 6.4, I think you need to println everything :(
for UI use XCPShowView function from XCPlayground library.
So first you need to import XCPlayground, then:
XCPShowView("your title", yourUIViewObject)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to: 
View ➤ Assistant Editor ➤ Show Assistant Editor in XCode menu 
or simply press (⌥⌘⏎)